# Adding element to JSON in Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, json

I m using Eclipse and Android project. I have parsed the JSON and have contents as String. I have a JSON like:

```
{        
"state":{
"updated":"2012-07-16T19:20:30",
"value":604,
"variables":{
    "var1":12,
    "var2":47,
    "var3":77,
    "var4":77
    }
} 
}
```

I want to add "var5":value to JSON in Android. The value could be String, decimal,array, integer etc. I want to have the updated JSON as String. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new JSONObject from the String by:

```
String str="{        
"state":{
"updated":"2012-07-16T19:20:30",
"value":604,
"variables":{
    "var1":12,
    "var2":47,
    "var3":77,
    "var4":77
    }
} 
}";
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(str);
```

now get JSONObject with key "variables" from this object by:

```
JSONObject variables=jsonObject.getJSONObject("variables");
```

to add a new value to this JSONObject use:

```
variables.put("var5", newValue);
```

now put this json object variables to jsonObject.

```
jsonObject.put("variables", variables);
```

and get This jsonObject as a String:

```
String strResult=jsonObject.toString();
```

Comment: Ya I have done that. I have the old JSON contents in a String. But, how will I get the updated JSON as String(as I have to put it on server)? I m new to Android, so pls help even if my question is simple @jeet

Comment: you did that? you could have said.

Comment: I have iterated and able to see the new value in LogCat. But just want to know how will get a String variable of my new JSON?